# Using srcsets to deliver images for different browser widths

Tags: wordpress, responsive, srcset

Using WordPress, I uploaded an image that's 400x200. It produced a 'medium' and 'thumbnail' size. I'm trying to load 'thumbnail' in so that it's used for, let's say, 768px and higher and the 'full' size, so 400x200, will be used 767 and lower.

I've got a function made, but it keeps returning `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset` to be false. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
while ($sponsors->have_posts()) : $sponsors->the_post();  

  $src_id     = get_post_thumbnail_id();
  $src_url    = wp_get_attachment_url($src_id);
  $src_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset($src_id, 'thumbnail');
  $src_size   = wp_get_attachment_image_sizes($src_id);

  $html_out .= '<img src="' . $src_url . '" srcset="' . $src_srcset . '" sizes="' . $src_size . '" />';

  echo $html_out;

endwhile;
```

I am not sure why and what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What does `get_post_thumbnail_id()` return?

Comment: Also check out https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162616/wp-get-attachment-image-src-always-returns-false

Comment: @AndrewMyers it returns an ID that's different from the post id